# Can I add a hint clause to a materialized view in postgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-aurora, pg-hint-plan

Can I add a hint clause to a materialized view in PostgreSQL as follows? or is there another way?

ex1.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV1
/*+
IndexScan(tableA)
*/
SELECT...
```

ex2.

```
/*+
IndexScan(tableA)
*/
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW MV1
```

I tried both, but ex1 didn't work.

If possible, I'd like to do it ex1 way (include hint_plan in CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW query).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No. Postgres does not support hints. Post your full query and Explain Analyze. There may be other methods/techniques.

Comment: I am aware that pg_hint_plan itself can be used in PostgreSQL (created by NTTdata, unofficially), but does that mean it cannot be used in material view?

Comment: Why? What is the problem you try to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Hint clauses are not directly supported by PostgreSQL in CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW. Usually, hints are included in the question, like:

```
SELECT /*+ IndexScan(tableA) */ columns FROM MV1;
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  The MV has already been constructed by the point you are reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally, the hint works when the query is run upon initial construction, but then is ignored upon refresh.  Maybe this would best be addressed to pg_hint_plan's issue tracker.